# Unable to Change css on new ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, django

here is my html

```
<div id="tabs" >
              <ul class="cat-head">
              <li>All</li>
              {% for category in brandcategory %}
              <li id="cat{{category.id}}" onclick="sendBrandCategory(event, {{category.id}})">{{category}}</li>
              {% endfor %}
              </ul>    
          </div>
```

and here is the ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendBrandCategory(event, category) {
          var data = { category : category , action:'inventory'};
          $.ajax({        
              type: "GET",
              url: "{% url 'storeView'  user=store.user %}",
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                  var thumb = $(data).find('#brand');
                  $('#brand').html(thumb);  
                  $('#cat'+ category).css({'background-color':'black'});  
                },
              error: function(response, error) {
                  alert(error);  
              }
          });
      }

</script>
```

On ajax success i am able to set the first li element css but on clicking the second li element the first element css still remains on the page.I want one li element to have background color on ajax success at a time.how can i achieve this.thank you

Comment: @UnknownUser Kindly explain how is it possible to make AJAX functions possible in a snippet?

Comment: Before `$('#cat'+ category).css({'background-color':'black'});` please remove background color of all `li` elements. Then it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the last items before asign the new background:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function sendBrandCategory(event, category) {
          var data = { category : category , action:'inventory'};

          // see here:
          $('[id^="cat"]').each(function() {
               $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow'); // I put yellow but you can put the color you need
          });
          $.ajax({        
              type: "GET",
              url: "{% url 'storeView'  user=store.user %}",
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                  var thumb = $(data).find('#brand');
                  $('#brand').html(thumb);  
                  $('#cat'+ category).css({'background-color':'black'});  
                },
              error: function(response, error) {
                  alert(error);  
              }
          });
      }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function sendBrandCategory(event, category) {
           var data = { category : category , action:'inventory'};
           $.ajax({        
               type: "GET",
               url: "{% url 'storeView'  user=store.user %}",
               data: data,
               success: function(data) {
                   var thumb = $(data).find('#brand');
                   $('#brand').html(thumb);  
                   $("ul.cat-head li").css({'background-color':'none'});            
                   //this is new line added
                   $('#cat'+ category).css({'background-color':'black'});  
                },
              error: function(response, error) {
                  alert(error);  
              }
          });
      }
</script>
```